# Can definite and indefinite articles be used interchangeably?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

I was going to say:

> Pronouns and/or be/have/do are occasionally omitted in spoken English at the beginning of **the** sentence.

But then I thought, I don't have any particular sentence in mind here. So it must be **a**. But then I looked into [the rules](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-definite-article):

> to generalize about a whole class or species, usually of plants or animals. A singular noun is used for this purpose. The first example means ‘The elephant species is hunted.’
>
> The elephant is still hunted for its tusks.
>
> The snowdrop is the first flower to arrive in the new year.

Well, it says, "usually of plants or animals," but I have a reason to think the usage occasionally extends beyond the outlined limits. That is, **the** is sometimes used to mean something general. A class of something, one of a class of something. Which overlaps with usage of **a**.

And even if we take the previous sentence, I could probably say "with **the** usage of a" to mean a general action, could I?